# Redirect all requests on clasic asp global.asa file?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, global.asa

I tried to do a permanent redirect in the `Global.asa` file in my Classic ASP application by adding this code:

```
Sub Session_OnStart
  queryString= Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")
  url = "http://www.newdomain.com" & Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")
  If Len(queryString)<>0 Then
    url = url & "?" & queryString
  End If

  Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
  Response.AddHeader "Location", url
  Response.End()
End Sub
```

This works great the first time for one user because it's doing the redirect once per Session, but how can I do it on every request?

Comment: Why not just setup a redirect on the site in IIS, saves messing in the application?

Comment: I don't have access to the IIS, it's a shared hosting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Session.Abandon` to your sub, before the redirect. This will end the session and any new requests will start a new session.